# Error: GoogleMapsAPI is not defined for node-googlemaps

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3, google-api, npm, sails.js

I am using [node-googlemaps](https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps) to query the `Google Maps API` from Node js. I have created my Server API key as a Developer. According to the [this](https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps) documentation, I have to make a `publicConfig` variable with my *API* key and certain other parameters. My publicConfig variable is as follows:

```
 var gm = require('googlemaps');
 var publicConfig = {
  key: 'myKey',
  stagger_time:1000, // for elevationPath
  encode_polylines:false,
  secure:true // use https
};
 var gmAPI = new GoogleMapsAPI(publicConfig);
```

When I run the Code, I get the following error

```
 ReferenceError: GoogleMapsAPI is not defined
```

Can somebody help me on this issue?

Comment: Did you include the library correctly? Are you sure it's available?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To Resolve this issue I had include the following line of Code

```
var GoogleMapsAPI = require('googlemaps');
```